# MIT Scheme REPL history

Tags: linux, command-line, scheme, read-eval-print-loop, mit-scheme

I have been using MIT-Scheme for sometime now, and it works great. However, in the REPL mode, I really miss having a history of all the commands that I typed into it. It's very frustrating to retype a piece of code in case of a small typographical error.

How can I enable the `history` mode? (If such a thing exists)

Comment: Yes, this would be very nice to know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The program rlwrap adds command history and covenient editing to almost all command line tools.
http://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/uck/rlwrap/

Updated URL[11/2016]:
https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap

Answer (score 1):

[Edwin,](http://web.mit.edu/scheme_v9.0.1/doc/mit-scheme-user/Edwin.html#Edwin) the MIT/GNU Scheme text editor, provides a [special mechanism](http://web.mit.edu/scheme_v9.0.1/doc/mit-scheme-user/Edwin-REPL-Mode.html#Edwin-REPL-Mode) for interacting with Scheme read-eval-print loops: REPL buffers.

Each REPL buffer maintains a history of the expressions that were typed into it. Several commands allow you to access the contents of this history. The command M-p moves backwards through the history, inserting previously evaluated expressions at point. Likewise, M-n moves forward through the history. The commands C-c C-r and C-c C-s search backward and forward through the history for a particular string.

http://web.mit.edu/scheme_v9.0.1/doc/mit-scheme-user/Edwin-REPL-Mode.html

Comment: Actually, I was looking for something outside of Edwin, that's usable in the pure MIT-scheme REPL.

Comment: your solution is good for Windows which is lack of the cygwin, thanks.